# get the maximum value of enumeration constants at compile time

Tags: c++, enums

is there any way to get the maximum value of enumeration constants?

since the enum constants may have explicitly assigned values its not necessarily the last element. Mostly there is a constant called like XXX_cnt but in my case its not. Also the enum may be changed without my notice so just using the last element is error prone.

So is there any way?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<yourenum>::type>::max()` :p

Comment: @melak47 thats not exactly that i had in mind to be the expected output :)

Comment: It was meant as a joke ;-)

Comment: Could you add more details (or even sample) about what you want to achieve, because the more I read question, the more I think I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 3):

No. This is why sometimes you can find explicit definition of **max** and **min** in enumeration type:

```
enum e { zero, one, two, min = zero, max = two};
```

Comment: Is this still true with the new C++20/23 standards?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to wrap the enumeration in a class:

```
class CustomEnum
{
public:
    enum CustomEnumValues
    {
        // some values here
    };

    static CustomEnumValues Maximum()
    {
        // return the maximum value
    }
    // ...
};
```

If the enumeration changes, the class would also need to be updated.  One way to limit the changes is to have a `MAXIMUM` and `MINIMUM` enumeration value that is set to whatever the current maximum and minimum values are in the enumeration (so the `Maximum` function would simply return `MAXIMUM` always).  You can also add an implicit cast operator to cast the class to the enumeration directly.

Comment: yes but i have no influence of the definition of that enum. and if i wrap the enum at my side i have to track any changes in that enum to adapt my code.

Comment: so the answer to "how to get enum max" is to code a function returning enum max?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch This is true.  If you do not have control over the enumeration, you can also create your own enumeration that stores the minimum and maximum values of the existing enumeration.  Anytime the existing enumeration changes, you will have to make the corresponding changes to your enumeration.

Comment: @lizusek One method for doing so, yes.

Comment: @ZacHowland I totally agree, however I suppose this is the body of this function that OP is interested in

Answer (score 0):

You do not have reflection capabilities in C++ like you have in other languages. So unfortunately not possible.

Comment: theoretically there is no reflection capability required to get this knowledge. since all is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no elegant way for this but you can use [Enum classes](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-enum-just-isnt-enough-enumeration-c/184403955) and rely on compiler optimization.

Such classes has iterators, so you can iterate through all enums during runtime and found the biggest value, it actually costs nothing, because compiler notices that those values doesn't change during runtime so with optimizations enabled (not sure which level) compiler uses constant calculated during calculation.

Answer (score 0):

using constexpr one can insure that enum iterators strategy will give max value for enum classes.
Maybe template metaprograming allow it also.